# RegExp for Hangul in Ruby

Tags: regex, ruby

I'm trying to find some documentation of RegExp for hangul in Ruby.

I'd like to know if there's some option to match anything with ㅆ (핬, 싸, etc) or ㅏ (아, 가, 감), or only when a character is in batchim (for ex. match when ㅁ is in batchim, would match (암, 감, but not 마 ), or similar queries without long expressions.

Comment: Looks like `/[\u3131-\uD79D]/` [should work](https://rubular.com/r/mBFM3MvDaLWKTM) for you. BTW, `\p{Hangul}` will work, too.

Comment: It doesn't work because it will match all hangul. I'm looking for something more specific.

Comment: Then build your own character class.

Comment: That's what I'm asking. If I want to match all character with ㅏ, I need to write a long regexp with all the cases /가-갛라-랗,다,닿.../. With batchim is even worse. I'm trying to find if there's any more simple way to do it.

Comment: No, custom sets are defined with your own character classes. If it is long, it is long.